# Adding and deleting a clone in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've managed to get my adding a clone button working but im now having trouble with getting the delete button to work. Wondering if people can see the problem im guessing im totally wrong.

This is the code in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/AFfa2/

```
<div class="question">
                    <div class="questiontext">
                    20. Details of Children
                    </div>  
                <div id="question20">
                    <div class="questiontitles">
                        Family Name<br>
                        Given Names<br>
                        Sex<br>
                        Date of Birth<br>
                        Country of Birth
                    </div>
                    <div class="questionanswer">
                    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
                    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
                    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
                    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
                    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Child" class="question">
                    <div id="addChild" class="questiontitles">
                        <input type="button" value="Add Child Info"> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="deleteChild" class="questionanswers">
                        <input type="button" value="Delete Child Info">
                    </div>
                </div>

$("#addChild").click(function(){
        var newElement =$('<div/>').html($("#question20").html());
        newElement.addClass('input');
        $("#question20").after(newElement);
    }); 

    $("#deleteChild").click(function() {
    if(childId > 0) childId--;
    $("#child"+childId).slideUp();
    if ($("#deleteChild").css("display") == "none") $("#deleteChild").slideUp();
    });
```

Comment: you want to delete the last div?

Comment: The add button adds the Question20 div then i want to be able to delte the div that was just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $("#addChild").click(function(){
  $(".question20:last").after($(".question20:first").clone(true));
 });


 $("#deleteChild").click(function() {
 if($(".question20").length!=1)
   $(".question20:last").remove();
});



 <div class="question20"> //and the div got class instead of id since cloning the div with same id is not good
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AFfa2/4/

Answer (score 2):

Try this Answer

```
$("#addChild").click(function () {
            var newElement = $('<div id="childdiv"/>').html($("#question20").html());
            newElement.addClass('input');
            $("#question20").after(newElement);
            childId++;
        });
        $("#deleteChild").click(function () {
            var div = document.getElementById('childdiv');
            if (div) {
                div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AFfa2/3/)

updated code posted by [**rps**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587132/rps)

as it deletes all the div elements. Modified it not delete the original form element.

```
$("#addChild").click(function () {
    $(".question20:last").after($(".question20:first").clone(true));
});


$("#deleteChild").click(function () {
    if ($('.question20').length > 1) {
        $(".question20:last").remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HuEUH/1/)

```
<div id="question20" class="input">
                <div id="question20">20. Details of Children
                    <br>Family Name
                    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
                    <br>Given Names
                    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
                    <br>Sex
                    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
                    <br>Date of Birth
                    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
                    <br>Country of Birth
                    <input type="text" name="children" class="textbox">
                    <br>
                </div>
                        <div id="removeChild">
                            <input type="button" value="Remove Child Info">                                 
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div id="addChild" class="input">
                <input type="button" value="Add Child Info"> 
            </div>
```

jQuery code

```
    $("#addChild").click(function(){
    var newElement =$('<div/>').html($("#question20").html());
    newElement.addClass('input');
    $("#question20").after(newElement);
});

$('#removeChild').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
$("#deleteChild").click(function() {
    $('#question20').parent().children('.input:last').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HLpJP/

You've got issues around where your inserting the new rows however. Your inserting new rows after `question20`, these will appear before existing ones. The remove method will remove the last one so might not be the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/AFfa2/5/

add remove button

```
<div id="removeChild">
                <input type="button" value="Remove Child Info"> 
            </div>
```

and jquery

```
    $("#removeChild").click(function(){
```

$('div.input').get($(this).length).remove();
});

you need to change buttons div classes